# from one ASP page to other with variable and change connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

i have 2 ASP pages in first page the user choose the database name and in other page take the database name and change the connection string to other database
how i can pass a variable from one page to other by button click and how i receive this variable in other page and how to change the connection string
the connection string is in web.config like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User Id=sa;Password=sa; Connect Timeout=10"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

plz help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the user choose the full connection string, it's huge security issue plus pretty cumbersome for the user himself.

Instead, have several connection strings in the config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User Id=sa;Password=sa; Connect Timeout=10"/>
    <add name="Westwind" connectionString="..."/>
    <add name="Eastwind" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then pass the **name** only on the URL e.g. *MyPage.aspx?connstringname=Eastwind* and finally use that parameter from the URL when you read the connection string:

```
string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Request.QueryString["connstringname"]].ConnectionString;
```